# Software SolaR Package: how to derive coefficients of the efficiency curve of the inverter

Tags: r

I am trying to use the R package solaR to calculate photovoltaic output.
My data is in a CSV file like the following sample, which I'm storing in a dataframe called “clean1”:

```
- Datetime          G0      Ta
- 01/01/2016 07:29  16.15   17.35
- 01/01/2016 08:29  61.43   17.95
- 01/01/2016 09:29  159.85  19.14
- 01/01/2016 10:29  424.38  21.62
- 01/01/2016 11:29  575.53  24.35
- 01/01/2016 12:29  636.21  25.85
- 01/01/2016 13:29  570.03  27.10
- 01/01/2016 14:29  466.20  28.09
- 01/01/2016 15:29  306.68  28.27
- 01/01/2016 16:29  138.46  27.98
```

This is my code:

```
library(solaR)
zI <- read.zoo(clean1,
header = TRUE, FUN = as.POSIXct, tz="Asia/Kolkata", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
lat <- 20
LocMeteo <- zoo2Meteo(zI, lat = lat, source = "XXXX")

mod1 =list(Vocn=44.9,Iscn=8.37,Vmn=35.48,Imn=8.05,Ncs=72,Ncp=1,CoefVT=-0.16, TONC=44)
gen1 <- list(Nms = 9, Nmp = 15)
# default inverter coefficients
inv1 = list(Ki = c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05), Pinv = 29400, Vmin = 125, Vmax = 500, Gumb = 21)

# South-facing, latitude used for tilt angle.
prod <- prodGCPV(lat = lat, modeTrk='fixed', dataRad = LocMeteo,
 modeRad = "bdI", keep.night=TRUE, sunGeometry='strous', corr ="BRL", beta=lat, alfa = 0, 
horizBright = TRUE,  module = mod1, generator = gen1, inverter = inv1)
```

As you can see, I've used default values for the inverter coefficients (Ki) and the result PV power values are clearly incorrect. My question is, how do I derive the coefficients of the efficiency curve of the inverter (I'm using  a generic 4.2 kW inverter) and thus create my own vector of three values for Ki?

Is there an example anywhere of how to do this? I'm struggling to interpret the reference:

> Baumgartner, F. P., Schmidt, H., Burger, B., Bründlinger, R., Haeberlin, H. and Zehner, M.: Status and Relevance of the DC Voltage Dependency of the Inverter Efficiency. 22nd European Photovoltaic Solar Energy Conference, 2007.

Comment: Do you really need to derive these coefficients? [This paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/41764555.pdf)'s Table 1, based on a survey cited in it, suggests sets of coefficients based on whether the inverter's efficiency is high or low. Not sure if this helps at all, or is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the time index of your data. Your time series is using local time, and it have to be converted to mean solar time in order to be used as an input to `prodGCPV`. The package `solaR` includes a function intended for this correction: `local2Solar`. Its help page provides an example related to your question, using data from [NREL-MIDC](https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/). This same dataset is used in the last example of the help page of `calcG0`. You may adapt the code of this example to your needs.

Regarding your question about the coefficients of a PV inverter, you need measurements of DC power (input) and AC power (output) of the inverter, and then use the equation 10 of the paper suggested in the comment (which disregard the voltage dependence) to extract them.